# How to upload file outside web server?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, upload

I want to upload files outisde web server like in d d drive  into servlets, I but I'm not able to upload them.

What I have to do to make functionality like this enable in Tomcat 6.0?

Comment: what have you tried and what doesn't work. What do you mean by "outside web server". You want to store them to a different location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought just to work. All you basically need to do is to obtain the uploaded file in flavor of an `InputStream` from the request body. You normally use [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload) for this. Then you can write it to any `OutputStream` you like the usual [Java IO](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/) way, such as `FileOutputStream`.

Assuming that you're actually using Apache Commons FileUpload which requires [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io) as a dependency, here's a basic example:

```
String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(fileItem.getName()); // Important!
File destination = new File("D:/path/to/files", filename);

InputStream input = null;
OutputStream output = null;

try {
    input = fileItem.getInputStream();
    output = new FileOutputStream(destination);
    IOUtils.copy(input, output);
} finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(input);
}
```

Alternatively you can also just use the Fileupload's convenienced `FileItem#write()` method:

```
String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(fileItem.getName()); // Important!
File destination = new File("D:/path/to/files", filename);

fileItem.write(destination);
```

For more examples, hints and tricks, check the FileUpload [User Guide](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) and [FAQ](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/faq.html).